# Can't get embedded OCSP to validate in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, bouncycastle, pdfbox, sign, ocsp

I am signing a PDF with Bouncy Castle and embedding an OCSP response in the PKCS7. I assemble the signed PDF with PDFBox, but I can't for the life of me get the resulting file to validate properly in Adobe Reader (the OCSP is not recognized). Since the OCSP responder requires signed requests, I have to embed the response in the file.

If someone would have any pointers at all, it would be much appreciated.

I presume it's easier to look at the actual signature/certs/OCSP than my code. The signed PDF is available here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TaSaQW0YXteUgtbUlEa0NhcGc

And the Base64-encoded signature is here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TaSaQW0YXtaEtPczRROTg4UDA

**Edit:**

When I look at the certificate in Adobe Reader, and check Revocation > Problems encountered, it says:

```
Certificate is not valid for the usage. Must sign the request.
```

The Revocation-section also says:

```
An attempt was made to determine whether the certificate is valid by doing 
a revocation check using the Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP).
```

So it seems that the embedded OCSP is skipped altogether.

**Edit 2:**

As per mkl's suggestion I updated the **nonce**-extension, by changing the following line:

```
DEROctetString extValue = new DEROctetString(nonce);
```

To this:

```
DEROctetString extValue = new DEROctetString(new DEROctetString(nonce)));
```

Resulting in the following DER-structure:

```
[1] (1 elem)
  SEQUENCE (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1.2ocspNonce(OCSP)
      OCTET STRING (1 elem)
        OCTET STRING IKhVULz41m7JWTa4swZXJPBm6Zs=
```

But I still get the same error messages in Adobe Reader. I have attached the updated document and base64-encoded signature:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TaSaQW0YXtVjNqRWlxbXg4T0U
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TaSaQW0YXtNC1CblZlUHV4dGs

**Edit 3:**

I compared the file to another version without the embedded OCSP response, and got this error in *Prolems encountered* in Adobe Reader:

```
Must sign the request.
```

Leading me to believe that the first part of the initial error was indeed from trying to validate the embedded OCSP-response:

```
Certificate is not valid for the usage.
```

I guess the certificate in question, would be the signing certificate of the OCSP-response. My own document is signed with the following certificate structure:

```
Root CA -> Bank (on EU Trust List) -> My Company
```

The OCSP is signed with the following structure:

```
Root CA -> External company (cert marked for OCSP signing)
```

Does the intermediary certificate in the document signing chain make the OCSP-signature invalid? Or can I somehow include missing pieces of the cert chain(s) to make it validate? Or is this perhaps not the problem?

Comment: Take a look at this thread... https://forums.adobe.com/thread/620434

Comment: joelgeraci: Thanks, but they are discussing bugs in Adobe Reader 9.X and BER decoding errors - not the same issue I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### OCSP Nonce encoding

The **nonce** extension in your OCSP response is encoded like this:

```
3405   45:                                   [1] {
3407   43:                                     SEQUENCE {
3409   41:                                       SEQUENCE {
3411    9:                                         OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         :                                           ocspNonce (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 48 1 2)
3422   28:                                         OCTET STRING 'EZrf5DVM/y1QFGUfydwBSOsxZ6s='
         :                                         }
         :                                       }
         :                                     }
```

This most likely corresponds to the **nonce** extension as you sent it in your request.

Remember, though, that the value of an extension is wrapped in an OCTET STRING by definition. Thus, your actual **nonce** value is the sequence of bytes given by the ASCII values of the characters `EZrf5DVM/y1QFGUfydwBSOsxZ6s=`, i.e. something completely untyped as far as ASN.1 is concerned.

But RFC 6960 *specifies, for the nonce extension, ASN.1 syntax that was missing in RFC 2560...*

```
Nonce ::= OCTET STRING
```

*(RFC 6960 sections 1 and 4.4.1)*

So your nonce value has to be an OCTET STRING instead of untyped as far as ASN.1 is concerned.

Thus, please try and wrap the value you chose for your **nonce** in an OCTET STREAM (which then, according to the `Extension` definition, will be wrapped in yet another OCTET STREAM).

#### Revocation information for all certificates

To make verification succeed without additional revocation information requests, the signature must bring along revocation information for all certificates involved except the (trusted) root certificates and other certificates marked accordingly.

Thus, you do not only need revocation information for your signer certificate and the intermediary bank certificate but also for the OCSP certificates of your embedded OCSP responses (unless they have the id-pkix-ocsp-nocheck extension).

If I read the ASN.1 dumps correctly, the OCSP certificate in your case does not have that extension. Thus, Adobe Reader will try to receive revocation information for it online, and if that does not work, it won't use your embedded OCSP responses.

#### OCSP service TLS certificate

As your signature does not bring along all required revocation information. Adobe Reader tries to receive them online. While doing so, it runs into errors.

The detailed error information I get are

> Certificate is not valid for the usage____________________________________________________________
>
> Certificate is not valid for the usage____________________________________________________________
>
> SSL certificate error.

And indeed, trying to access https://va1.bankid.no/ (the URL of the OCSP server) manually, I'm also been told about certificate issues.

You appear to get different errors. Did you install and trust some special certificates on your computer or in Adobe Reader?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you check out "Edit 2" in my question, and see if I understood you correctly? If so, it doesn't seem to be the culprit of the validation error.

Comment: @benwixen You understood me correctly; that error has been made by many implementers. That been cleared, I'm going to edit the answer to discuss why that fix does not suffice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Turns out it's basically unfixable right now, but the provider is working on some updates that should resolve my issues in the future.